# Did Chile's productivity/capita go up during Pinochet's reign?

Tags: economy, drugs, demographics, dictatorship

What effect did Pinochet's war on drugs and execution of drug users have on Chile's productivity per capita?

If you have data for the Philippines, that would be a bonus.

Comment: There is no evidence to show that drug eradication can help improve production. Job and production issues cause by the dysfunctional institution, which is the cause of the drugs abuse rampage.

Comment: @mootmoot: Bunch of unproven claims there, such as disfunctional institutions causing drue use.  Ever consider that maybe people just like using drugs?

Comment: @jamesqf  I don't think you it is a good argument on "people just like using drugs". Even drug abuses population in develop country like USA is just a small fraction.  In addition, illicit drugs are fetching good money in USA.  While in the dysfunctional country, typical Joe can't afford illicit drugs, there is hardly any heavily armed "drug lords" as compare to those in Mexico border.

Comment: @mootmoot: I don't understand just what you're trying to say here.  What reason would people have for using (let's avoid loaded terms like 'abuse') drugs, other than that they expect to enjoy the effects?  If "typical Joe" can't afford them, he doesn't use them.  Basically the same reason I don't fly my private jet off to tropical islands - can't afford one :-)  And of course, the "heavily armed drug lords" are just an artifact of illegalization.  Legal businesses have heavily-armed protection forces, too, it's just that they're called "police".

Comment: @jamesqf  If you like economic study, go compare the "border drugs price" around the world.

Comment: @mootmoot: That would be irrelevant, unless the study has found a place where production and sale is completely legal.  A better comparison would be to legal (and not highly taxed) drugs like coffee, tea, and chocolate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OECD has [productivity data](https://data.oecd.org/chart/4TTY) (GDP per hour worked) going back to 1986, so it has data for the last 4 years of Pinochet's rule. In each of those years, productivity increased.

On a scale in which 2010 is 100, Chilean productivity increased from 43 to 47 between 1986 and 1990. This is typical productivity growth for most countries at the time. There is no particular evidence in these data that Pinochet had much effect on productivity. However, Chilean productivity grew sharply between 1994 and 1997. Which could be seen as a delayed response to his downfall in 1990 or could be unrelated/cyclical changes.